# is it possible to add Watermark on product images for particular category in magento

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to add different watermark for new products and also for free shipping products. But in magento only it adding one watermark for complete store in admin->system->Configaration->Design here we can add watermark(It wiil add for complete store images). So, Please help me is it possible to add multiple watermarks in magento. 
Thank You.

Comment: It's not possible from magento admin though. You have to code manually for that.

Comment: Thanks for reply. May i Know How to add manually?